# I have a error in my batch api operations, and I don't find the solution

Tags: 7, batch-operations

Hello I run this in a form_submit function:

```
<?php
function generate_xls_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {



$data = array();
  $information = '';

  if($form_state['values']['SelectFormstackForm']){
    $data['FormstackForm'] = $form_state['values']['SelectFormstackForm'];
  }
  if($form_state['values']['FromDate']){
    $data['FromDate'] = $form_state['values']['FromDate'];
  }
  if($form_state['values']['ToDate']){
    $data['ToDate'] = $form_state['values']['ToDate'];
  }

  //if we don't have 3 options, que can not retrieve all we need.
  if(count($data) != 3){
    return NULL;
  }

  // we will retrieve all the nid to get them the lead field values.
  $IdList = submission_generate_xls_get_leads_id($data);

  //total de resultados encontrados.
  $cantidadIdList = count($IdList);

  // Get formstack form field labels from database.
  $labels = submission_generate_xls_get_fomrstack_field_labels($data['FormstackForm']);

  //cargamos la clase de PHPExcel.php
  require_once 'Classes/PHPExcel.php';

  date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
  // Create new PHPExcel object
  $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

  // Set properties
  $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("Captalis")
                 ->setLastModifiedBy("Captalis")
                 ->setTitle("Leads generados del formulario ." . $data['FormstackForm'])
                 ->setSubject("Leads")
                 ->setDescription("")
                 ->setKeywords("office 2007 openxml php")
                 ->setCategory("Customers");

  //montamos el encabezado
  $vocal = 'B';
  foreach ($labels as $key => $value) {
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue($vocal . '3', $value);
    ++$vocal;
  }

  // Rename worksheet
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Leads');            

  //build batch operations.
  foreach ($IdList as $key => $value) {
    $operations[] = array('batch_generate_xls_row', array($value, $key, $cantidadIdList));
  }

  // configure a batch
  $batch = array(
      'title' => t('Build excell.'),
      'operations' => $operations,
      'init_message' => t('Batch is starting.'),
      'progress_message' => t('Batch is running...'),
      'error_message' => t('Batch has encountered an error.'),
      'finished' => 'submission_generate_xls_finished',
  );

  batch_set($batch);
}
?>
```

this is my batch functions:

```
/**
 *
 *
 */
function batch_generate_xls_row($value, $key, $cantidadIdList, &$context) {


  if (!isset($context['sandbox']['progress'])) {
    $context['sandbox']['progress'] = 0;
    $context['sandbox']['current_node'] = 0;
    $context['sandbox']['max'] = $cantidadIdList;
  }
  $values = submission_generate_xls_get_leads_values($value);

  $vocal = 'B';
  $integer = $key+4;
  foreach ($values as $key => $value) {
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue($vocal . $integer, $value);
    ++$vocal;
  }

  $context['message'] = t('Loading node "@title"', array('@title' => $node->title)) . ' ' . $operation_details;

  $context['sandbox']['progress']++;
  $context['sandbox']['current_node'] = $value;
  $context['message'] = 'este es el procesamiento de ' . $value;
  if ($context['sandbox']['progress'] != $context['sandbox']['max']) {

    $context['finished'] =  $context['sandbox']['progress'] / $context['sandbox']['max'];
  }
}


/**
 *
 *
 */

function submission_generate_xls_finished($success, $results, $operations) {
  if ($success) {
    // Here we could do something meaningful with the results.
    // We just display the number of nodes we processed...

    drupal_set_message(t('The excell is done'));
    drupal_set_message(t('The final result was "%final"', array('%final' => end($results))));

    // Set active sheet index to the first sheet, so Excel opens this as the first sheet
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

    // Redirect output to a client’s web browser (Excel2007)
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="01simple.xlsx"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
    $objWriter->save('php://output');
    exit;

  }
  else {
    // An error occurred.
    // $operations contains the operations that remained unprocessed.
    $error_operation = reset($operations);
    drupal_set_message(t('An error occurred while processing @operation with arguments : @args', array('@operation' => $error_operation[0], '@args' => print_r($error_operation[0], TRUE))));
  }
}
```

And this is the error watchdog give me:

```
Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'batch_generate_xls_row' not found or invalid function name in _batch_process() (line 284 of /home/oscar/webapps/www/drupal/drupal7/includes/batch.inc).
```

Any help?

Thanks

Oskar

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I presume batch_generate_xls_row is not defined in your .module file. In this case you need to specify the file in the batch definition:

```
<?php

$batch = array(
    ...
    'file' => drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/pages.inc',
);
?>
```

See [batch_set()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/batch_set/7) documentation for reference.

Comment: Also see this answer if this solution doesn't work http://stackoverflow.com/a/6590563/1449475. Move your batch function into the .module file